# AspectJ Compiler problems with kotlin delegation in type hierarchy

Tags: java, compiler-errors, kotlin, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

**NOTICE**

TLDR; I discovered that this was simply an environmental problem. The JAR with the kotlin code had old class files that caused unexpected problems that the compiler was 100% handling correctly.

I think that there was another class file in the JAR that I was trying to depend upon that was called `SimpleLink` that was a class instead of an interface. The Gradle Kotlin compile plugin didn't remove these classes when I removed the `.kt` files. LPT: Run the Gradle clean task before trying to publish, even if you are only publishing to maven local.

---

I'm having a problem with aspectj linking against code that uses kotlin classes from another project.

The aspectJ compiler is running version `1.8.6`.

My particular problem is that, I keep seeing this:

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type ExtendedSimpleLink to SimpleLink`

I have a type hierarchy where `ExtendedSimpleLink extends LinkDecorator` where `LinkDecorator` is written in kotlin and compiled in another project and `ExtendedSimpleLink` is java compiled with the aspectj compiler.

`LinkDecorator` looks like this:

```
abstract class LinkDecorator(
    private val decorated : SimpleLink
) : SimpleLink by decorated {
    override fun hashCode(): Int = decorated.hashCode()

    override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean = decorated == other
}
```

I have no idea why the aspectj compiler can't figure out the type hierarchy.
It should be looking at the bytecode for `LinkDecorator` and saying that obviously `ExtendedSimpleLink` is an instance of a `SimpleLink`.

As an example, the following code (trying to be compiled by the aspectJ compiler):

```
final class ExtendedSimpleLink extends LinkDecorator
{

    private final Double something;

    private final Object somethingElse;


    private ExtendedSimpleLink(
            final SimpleLink decorated,
            final Object somethingElse,
            final Double something)
    {
        super(decorated);
        this.somethingElse = somethingElse;
        this.something = something;
    }


    public static ExtendedSimpleLink from(final SimpleLink decorated)
    {
        if (decorated instanceof ExtendedSimpleLink)
        {
            return (ExtendedSimpleLink) decorated;
        }
        return new ExtendedSimpleLink(decorated, null, null);
    }
}
```

Compiling the above class gives this error from maven:

```
[ERROR] /Users/[user]/work/tmp/[project]/Core/src/main/java/com/company/core/engine/fitting/ExtendedSimpleLink.java:50:0::0 The return type is incompatible with LinkDecorator.getFabricLinkMetricEnhancement()
[ERROR] error at if (decorated instanceof ExtendedSimpleLink)
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /Users/[user]/work/tmp/[project]/Core/src/main/java/com/company/core/engine/fitting/ExtendedSimpleLink.java:58:0::0 Incompatible conditional operand types SimpleLink and ExtendedSimpleLink
[ERROR] error at return (ExtendedSimpleLink) decorated;
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

IntelliJ seems completely fine with this code. I think that it using the JavaC compiler for linting however.

My questions are, why is this happening? Is there a known problem in the AspectJ compiler? Are there similar problems with interop with groovy and the aspectJ compiler for example?

**Update**

I've tried adding the following to see if it solves the problem:

```
final class ExtendedSimpleLink extends LinkDecorator implements SimpleLink {
    // same as above...
}
```

Now I have all the same exceptions as before but with a new exception added to the mix:

```
[ERROR] error at final class ExtendedSimpleLink extends LinkDecorator implements SimpleLink
[ERROR] ^^^^^^^^^
[ERROR] /Users/[user]/work/tmp/[project]/Core/src/main/java/com/company/core/engine/fitting/ExtendedSimpleLink.java:23:0::0 The type SimpleLink cannot be a superinterface of ExtendedSimpleLink; a superinterface must be an interface
```